# Intel CPU names history

Tags: cpu

Why do the names of so many Intel CPUs start with 80?
For example 8008, 8086, 8088, 80186, and many others.

Does the number mean something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a model number that doesn't mean anything specifically.  Intel has historically made all kinds of different chips for different purposes.  The 8000 series (like the 4000 series before it) were microprocessors.  Intel also makes controller chips for various devices, which were modeled in the 3000 and 6000 series.

Originally, the "8" meant 8-bit, but obviously that's not a distinction anymore.  All Intel microprocessors start with an 8 now -- including the latest and greatest Core i7 Haswell chips, which carry the model number 80648.

Interesting trivia bite:
Intel's PCI Vendor ID is 8086.  So if you see an unknown device in Device Manager, and it's hardware ID (on the details tab of its properties dialog) starts with `PCI\VEN_8086`, then you know whose web site to visit for the driver ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It all began with 4004, which was a 4 Bit microprocessor. Then the 8008 came, which was an 8 bit processor, as well as 8080 and 8085. 16 Bit processors began with 8086, with 8088, 80186 and 80286 following. 80386 and 80486 are 32 Bit processors. Then Intel abandoned the numbers and called their processors Pentium.

Comment: I know about it, but why  all of it has 80?

Comment: Mainly because 8080 was a true success, with other company making compatible devices like Zilog Z80. In those years, 80 was a symbol of the beginning story for microprocessors, so Intel chose to use it in all following products.